# ADB and Fastboot cannot find my Nexus 5

Tags: android, adb, fastboot

I've been trying to root my Nexus 5, but whenever I try to use ADB or Chainfire's .bat file, it sticks on . I've tried using the command "adb devices", and it returns a blank list. I've tried installing the recommended drivers from the android SDK, resetting my phone to factory default, and I've even tried the rooting process on both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows 8. I've looked at multiple tutorials and youtube walk-throughs but NOTHING has fixed my problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This site is not for general tech support.

Comment: If your on windows you need to download the USB driver for the Nexus Device.

Comment: Do you enable ADB debugging in Developers menu?

Comment: I've enabled USB debugging, I dont know about ADB debugging specifically

Comment: Although the user is not actually trying to do development, they are trying to utilize the **development tools** and those are explicitly on topic here.  They'd face exactly the same adb problem if doing everyday app development, or fastboot problem if fixing a bug in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the driver.  If you have downloaded the Google USB drivers, you want the one listed as "Composite USB device"

Install it via Device Manager in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings --> storage --> tap upper right corner (USB computer connection), uncheck MTP and check PTP. Fastboot should be detected after that.